# How do I integrate my Switch component into my Table component as a separate column, and have separate state on both?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I am new to React.js, and so far, I am loving it. I am still confused on the concept of stateful components, although. I am using Bootstrap tables to build my table, and my GET request for its data grab worked flawlessly. I am using the material-ui lib for my switch component as well (no need to reinvent the wheel here!)

Although, I am now trying to integrate a new column that will be a switch for each row in my table, and that, when toggled, changes the boolean of said switch to true/false, which will then send a PUT request down to my backend. I have not built my PUT request yet, as I cannot get this UI portion functioning. Here is my code so far, and the dumby UI works, but I don't know how to integrate the stateful render I defined in `NodeTableContainer` at `<SwitchState/>` and `SwitchState()`, into my definition at `selectionRenderer: Switches` in my `NodeTable` component. The stateful render does render a toggle switch under the table, essentially as its own independent component. But I want to integrate that toggle switch component in `const selectRow = {mode: 'checkbox', clickToSelect: true,selectionRenderer: Switches}`. Here is my code, and I hope my I have explained my issue well. I have Googled endlessly, but I believe my own ignorance has blocked my from discovering the answer I need.

`Table Component (NodeTable)`

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Row,
    Col,
    Card,
    CardBody,
} from 'reactstrap';
import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import ToolkitProvider, { Search, CSVExport, ColumnToggle } from 'react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit';
import paginationFactory from 'react-bootstrap-table2-paginator';
import 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes';
import Switches from './Switch'

    const columns = OMIT
    
    const defaultSorted = [
        {
            dataField: 'id',
            order: 'asc',
        },
    ]
    const TableWithSearch = (props) => {
    
    
        const { SearchBar } = Search;
        const { ExportCSVButton } = CSVExport;
    
        const selectRow = {
            mode: 'checkbox',
            clickToSelect: true,
            selectionRenderer: Switches
    
        }
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <h4 className="header-title">OMIT</h4>
                    <p className="text-muted font-14 mb-4">OMIT</p>
    
                    <ToolkitProvider
                        bootstrap4
                        keyField="fqn"
                        data={props.data}
                        columns={columns}
                        columnToggle
                        search
                        exportCSV={{ onlyExportFiltered: true, exportAll: false }}>
                        {props => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                        <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
    
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col className="text-right">
                                        <ExportCSVButton {...props.csvProps} className="btn btn-primary">
                                            Export CSV
                                        </ExportCSVButton>
    
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
    
                                <BootstrapTable
                                    {...props.baseProps}
                                    bordered={false}
                                    defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
                                    pagination={paginationFactory({ sizePerPage: 5 })}
                                    selectRow={selectRow}
                                    wrapperClasses="table-responsive"
                                />
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                    </ToolkitProvider>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        );
    };
    
    export default TableWithSearch;
```

`Switch Component`

```
    // @flow
import React from 'react';
import 'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes';
import './Switch.css'
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';

export default function Switches({ isOn, handleToggle }) {

    return (
        <div>
            <Switch
                checked={isOn}
                onChange={handleToggle}
                name="checkedA"
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

`Parent Component (NodeTableContainer)`

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
    import Switch from './Switch';
    import App from './index';
    
    
    export default class MainComp extends React.Component {
    
    
        state = {
            nodesData: [],
            chartRef: [],
            conn: [],
            switchstate: [],
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('OMIT')
                .then(res => {
                    const nodestate = res.data.map(x => x.nodestate);
                    for (var i = 0; i < nodestate.length; i++) {
                        if (nodestate[i] == 'up') {
    
                            nodestate[i] = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            nodestate[i] = false;
                        }
                    }
                    this.setState({ nodesData: res.data, switchstate: nodestate });
    
    
                })
    
        }
        render() {
            return (
                < >

                   <App data={this.state.nodesData} checked={this.state.switchstate} />,
                   <SwitchState />
                </>
        )
    }
}
function SwitchState() {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(false);
    console.log(value)
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Switch
                isOn={value}
                onColor="#EF476F"
                handleToggle={() => setValue(!value)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also, my SwitchState component is in a dumby form as you will see, until I can see the log showing its boolean state changing. Also, `nodestate` in the `NodeTableContainer` was my pathetic try at pulling data via the same state data. That is nonfunctional as you will also see. I will build the state properly once I can get this figured out, or you wonderful individuals aid me in this as well. Again, I am showing my ignorance here, so if there is an easier way, or if I am using an odd flavor of libs for this, please let me know. I want to learn and thrive. If you have a solution of your own, that's a completely different flavor, I plea to you to share it! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out for react-bootstrap. I fat arrowed in the `formatter`, and passed the state to `formatExtraData`. I then pass state from my component that holds all state, and it works flawlessly. Time to integrate my PUT request in with the event handler!

Below are my changes in code:

`Table Component`

```
export default class TableComp extends React.Component

                    formatter: (cell, row, index, extra) => {
                        if (cell === 'up') {
                            cell = true
                        }
                        else {
                            cell = false
                        }

                        return (
                            <div>
                                <Switch
                                    checked={cell}
                                    onChange={extra.handle}
                                    name={row.name}
                                    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )
                    },
                    formatExtraData: { handle: this.props.handleClick }
```

`Parent Component (Holds all state)`

```
handleClick = (e) => {

        var indexFound = this.state.data.findIndex(y => y.name === e.target.name.toString())

        let data= [...this.state.data];
        let item = { ...data[indexFound] }

        if (item.state === 'up') {
            item.state = 'down'

        }
        else {
            item.state = 'up'
        }

        data[indexFound] = item

        this.setState({ data})

    }
```